# rescue に書く例外クラスの調べ方

Tags: ruby

MySQL にアクセスする Ruby スクリプトで

```
Mysql2::Error::TimeoutError: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction: ...
```

のような例外が時々出るので

```
mysql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

5.times do
  begin
    mysql.execute(query)
  rescue Mysql2::Error::TimeoutError => e
    puts 'failed. retry after 60 secs'
    sleep 60
    next
  end
  break
end
```

のようなリトライ処理を挟んでみたところ

例外発生箇所は
`mysql.execute(query)`
なんですが
`rescue Mysql2::Error::TimeoutError => e`
に引っかかってないようで 1 回で終了してしまいます

rescue に書く捉えたい例外クラス名はどうやって調べればいいのでしょうか

Comment: `mysql` オブジェクトは `ActiveRecord::Base` クラスのインスタンスなので、実際には `Mysql2::Error::TimeoutError` 例外が発生しているのではなくて、それをラップした `ActiveRecord` 系の何かの例外が発生しているのではないかと思います。エラーメッセージの前後に何かそれに関する情報がないでしょうか。

Comment: (ActiveRecord::LockWaitTimeout) というのがエラーメッセージの最後にありましたがこれでしょうか。次再現するのがいつになるかわからないのですがとりあえずこっちに書き換えて試してみます！　Error で終わってるのでてっきり例外クラスの派生なのかと思い込んでしまいました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

マニュアルに書いてなくてわからないなら、全ての例外のスーパークラスである`Exception`で捕捉して、クラス名を調べれば良いのではないでしょうか。

```ruby
class Foo < Exception; end
class Bar < Foo; end

begin
  raise Bar, "timeout"
rescue Exception => e
  puts e.class # Bar
end
```

ついでにクラス階層を調べてみるとか。

```ruby
class Foo < Exception; end
class Bar < Foo; end

def puts_hierarchy(obj)
  klass = obj.class
  hierarchies = [klass]
  super_klass = klass.superclass
  while !super_klass.nil?
    hierarchies << super_klass
    super_klass = super_klass.superclass
  end
  puts hierarchies.join(' < ')
end

begin
  raise Bar, "timeout"
rescue Exception => e
  puts_hierarchy(e) # Bar < Foo < Exception < Object < BasicObject
end
```